# how display result of findall() in CGridView?

Tags: yii

i want to display data in CGridView by findall() with condation

```
  public function actiondatabase($id){

    $model=Lecture::model()->findAll('subject_id=2');
    if(isset($_GET['Lecture']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Lecture'];

    $this->render('database',array(
        'model'=>$model,'dep'=>$id
    ));
```

in view database.php

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'lecture-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
  'id',
'name'
));
```

![this is the result of my code and now what should if do][help]

Answer (score 1):

CGridView expects a dataProvider, in your case a CActiveDataProvider, since you want to retreive data from your database. You can add the same properties as a findAll() for the CActiveDataProvider (like 'conditions', 'order', 'with' etc.), example:

**Model:**

```
public function myDataProvider()
{

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'subject_id=2',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20,
        ),
    ));

    return $dataProvider;

}
```

**View:**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'lecture-grid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->myDataProvider(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
         'id',
         'name'
));
```

Comment: and then i should use $model=new Lecture('search'); or $model=Lecture::model()->findAll();?

Comment: No, CActiveDataProvider does the 'findAll()' for you. Take a look here if you want to learn how the gridview works: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/381/cgridview-clistview-and-cactivedataprovider/